# count number of elements in a time window pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I want to count the number of occurrences of an IP address in a time window of an hour.

Here is my df

```
         Timestamp                   IpAddress
4695    2021-12-03 13:24:04.303964  192.168.1.1
4696    2021-12-03 13:24:04.585239  192.168.1.2
4697    2021-12-03 13:24:05.788292  192.168.1.1
4698    2021-12-03 13:24:05.819568  192.168.1.1
4699    2021-12-03 13:24:05.835315  192.168.1.2
4700    2021-12-03 13:34:05.850787  192.168.1.1
4701    2021-12-03 14:24:05.975795  192.168.1.2
4702    2021-12-03 14:24:06.366415  192.168.1.2
4703    2021-12-03 14:24:06.382064  192.168.1.2
4704    2021-12-03 14:24:06.741445  192.168.1.1
```

What I would like:

```
         Timestamp           IpAddress    Occurrences
4695    2021-12-03 13:25:00 192.168.1.1       3
4696    2021-12-03 13:25:00 192.168.1.2       2
4703    2021-12-03 14:25:00 192.168.1.2       3
4704    2021-12-03 14:25:00 192.168.1.1       2
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
df_ip['Occurrences_IP'] = df_ip.reset_index().set_index('Timestamp').groupby('IpAddress').rolling('1H').count()
```

However it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

I also tried this:

```
df_ip['Occurrences'] = (
        df_ip.groupby(
            ['IpAddress', pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='1H')]
        ).cumcount() + 1
)
```

but it is a cumulative sum, not a count every hour.

thanks

Comment: Can you explain why, in your expected output, all your timestamps are `2021-12-03 13:25:00` and `2021-12-03 14:25:00`?

Comment: Hi, just wrote this quickly, I don't think it should be 13:25:00, I just want a rolling window on the hour

Comment: Do you want to floor each time to the hour - i.e., `13:00 - 13:59` would all become `13:00` or do you want to look at each hour from the current timestamp so `13:24` would look for `13:24-14:24`

Comment: good question, I think both are fine, but maybe floor each time would be better.

I might have a solution: ```df_ip.groupby('IpAddress').resample('1H').apply(lambda s: s.value_counts().head(10))```
I have to check whether it is giving me the expected results. Only downside is I have [] instead of 0

Comment: If you want the floor, avoid the `apply` and `lambda` (which can be slow) and just do `df.groupby([df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('1h'), 'IpAddress']).count()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so both solutions can work:

```
df.groupby([df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('1h'), 'IpAddress']).count()
```

or, if you have `Timestamp` as index

```
df_ip.groupby('IpAddress').resample('1H').apply(lambda s: s.value_counts().head(10))
```